# Regarding Types: Strictly speaking, is $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

So far it never occurred to me to question whether $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ was actually a correct assertion. However, *is* this assertion really correct, strictly speaking? The type `real number` is not the type `integer` and when constructing the integers from pairs of natural numbers by the equivalence relation $(a,b), (c,d) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}. (a,b) \sim (c,d) \iff a + d = b + c$, no natural number actually gets explicitly... promoted lets say.... into an integer. Saying that $a \in \mathbb{N} = [(a,0)] \in \mathbb{Z}$ is just a convention it seems to me.

Would it therefore not actually be correct to say that the integers contain a subset that is isomorphic under the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ to the natural numbers, but does not actually contain the natural numbers?

Comment: Personally, I suggest the word "none" is the predecessor to the number 1 in domain $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Technically*, $\Bbb N\not\subseteq \Bbb Q$, with any usual construction. However, the natural inclusion $\iota:\Bbb N\hookrightarrow \Bbb Q$ is so natural and intuitive that most people think of $\Bbb N$ and $\iota(\Bbb N)$ as *equal* and not just isomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you are right that as defined $\mathbb{N}$ is isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ but is not contained in $\mathbb{Z}$.  However, this is cumbersome and so we identify elements under the isomorphism so that we can pretend that $\mathbb{N}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your point of view.  If you construct $\mathbb Q$ as stated, then  yes,  all you have is an isomorophic copy of $\mathbb N$, not $\mathbb N$ itself.   If you look at it from a "The rational numbers exist as objects in and of themselves" point of view, then you can actually have a true subset